# React Select dropdown onChange filter and reset to previous/original state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a dropdown where and i run a function onChange. After onChange i am filtering the current React state. This works, and i am able to filter on a unique value. However, i am not able to reset the state to the previous original state on change after switching to another dropdown select item.

```
handleStateOnChange = e => {
    let selectedWerkgever = e.target.value;

    const list = this.state.opleidingen.filter(({ opleiding_werkgever }) =>
        selectedWerkgever.includes(opleiding_werkgever)
    );

    this.setState({
        opleidingen: list,
        isResetButtonActive: true,
    });

    console.log('changed');
};
```

I am filtering on everything inside the array that includes "opleiding_werkgever". But how can i first revert back on change, and re-filter again?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to another dropdown on the same component or in the components sharing same state does not automatically reset the state. Your first call on `handleStateChange` filters the state and it will remain so until that component is unmounted. You could decide to retain the original `opleidingen` and then use it to reset the `opleidingen` when needed.

```
{
   opleidingen: list,
   isResetButtonActive: true,
   originalOpleidingen : list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store `selectedWerkgever` in state and use that to filter your drop down elements.  Keep the original list intact.

So simplify your handleStateOnChange:

```
handleStateOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      selectedWerkgever: e.target.value,
      isResetButtonActive: true
    });
};
```

And use this to filter your dropdown options:

```
<select>
  {this.state.opleidingen.filter(({ opleiding_werkgever }) =>
    this.state.selectedWerkgever.includes(opleiding_werkgever)).map(item=>
        <Option value={item} />}>)
 }
 ...
```